# The DELETE statement conflict REFERENCE constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get the error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   FK_DocYDocument1 - table DocYDocument, column SubDocID - Statement:
>   DELETE FROM DOCUMENT WHERE (ID=?) Parameter: 'D7FAA3CF...'

Table DocYDocument has columns

```
PK ID, FK DocID and FK SubDocID. 
And the keys PK_DocYDocument, FK_DocYDocument and FK_DocYDocument1.
```

FK_DocYDocument1 foreign key column is SubDocID and FK_DocYDocument foreign key column is DocID.

Is there a problem with database design or do I've to look for the error in the program?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have rows in `DocYDocument` that are referring to the `DOCUMENT` you are trying to delete.

You have to either delete the rows from `DocYDocument` with matching `DocID`

```
DELETE FROM DocYDocument WHERE DocID = ?
DELETE FROM DOCUMENT WHERE ID = ?
```

or change the constraint to do this automatically

```
ALTER TABLE DocYDocument
  DROP CONSTRAINT FK_DocYDocument;
ALTER TABLE DocYDocument
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DocYDocument
    FOREIGN KEY ( DocID )
    REFERENCES DOCUMENT ( ID )
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If `DocID` is nullable, you could instead do `ON DELETE SET NULL`, if you wish.