# How solve Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class HeadDoctor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }

    public int? InstitutionId { get; set; }
    public Institution? Institution { get; set; }
}

public class Institution
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public HeadDoctor HeadDoctor { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext:

```
builder.Entity<Institution>()
        .HasOne(institution => institution.HeadDoctor)
        .WithOne(headDoctor => headDoctor.Institution)
        .HasForeignKey<HeadDoctor>(headDoctor => headDoctor.InstitutionId);
```

Error:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_HeadDoctor_Institution_InstitutionId". The conflict occurred in database "MedicDb", table "dbo.HeadDoctor", column 'InstitutionId'.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you have data in other tables that references the data you are trying to delete.
This is a[similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866394/the-delete-statement-conflict-reference-constraint) 
You would need to drop and recreate the constraints.

Comment: how to make null for institutionId in the model of the heD doctor and not delete this model either